# first_name last_name paypal ipn

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am trying to send POST vars to paypal ipn like that:

```
<form class="form-horizontal paypal-button" method="post" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" target="_top" style="opacity: 1;">
<input type="hidden" name="button" value="buynow">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="vendedor@estadosbinarios.com">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
<input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="tax" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.estadosbinarios.com/pagos/paypal_ipn.php">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.estadosbinarios.com/pagos/success.php">
<input type="hidden" name="env" value="www.sandbox">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="JavaScriptButton_buynow">
<!-- Enable override of buyers’s address stored with PayPal . --> 
<input type="hidden" name="address_override" value="1">
<input id="nombre" name="first_name" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">
  <input id="nombre" name="last_name" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md">
</form>
```

But Paypal doesn´t care my vars first_name or last_name, paypal is always getting the vars from user account of paypal and overwriting that var.

Is there any way to choose my vars?

Comment: I 've tried your code, Paypal used your posted `first_name` and `last_name` in Billing information section. May be the reason in browser cache. Can you clear the browser cache and try again.

Comment: Hi Chunnu, Paypal is getting first_name and last_name when you pay with credit card (without paypal account), but if you are logged with paypal, it is giving you first_name and last_name from paypal account, I really want to use my POST vars from my form. By the way, I can´t use another vars created by me, paypal is not getting that :(

Comment: I dunno, I thought it was possible to choose my vars as well.

Answer (score 0):

When people pay with PayPal through it is indeed going to use the info provided from the shipping address of their account.  You can't get around this with Payments Standard like you're using.

You could switch to the Express Checkout API which would give you the option of collecting the buyers name, address, etc. and then passing that over to PayPal in a way that cannot be overridden.  This way you'd get whatever they typed into your site instead of relying on PayPal to provide those details.